# Properly scaling x-axis in accordance with pixels (Java)

Tags: java, graph, scaling, trigonometry

I am working on plotting a sin(x) graph for a school project. Currently I have everything working the way I want it to besides one thing: the scaling of the x axis.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
    int xStart = xShift;
    int xEnd = xShift;
    int yStart = getHeight() / 2;
    int yEnd = getHeight() / 2;
    int scale = getHeight() / 2;
    double constraint = 0.80;

    for (double i = Math.PI / 32; i <= Math.PI * 2; i+= Math.PI / 32){
        xEnd +=  (getWidth() - (2 * xShift) / 64);
        yEnd = (scale - ((int) Math.round(Math.sin(i) * scale * constraint))) ;
        g.drawLine(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd);
        xStart = xEnd;
        yStart = yEnd;
    }
```

Which produces something that looks like this: 
[image]

As you can see the red line indicating the sin graph ends short of where I need it to. For some reason I am unable to get the x coordinate of my 500x250 JFrame window to properly increment to the point where it will end at the proper position. I need it to stop where I have drawn the blue arrow, at the end of the gray line. What can I do to fix this? Thank you for your time and I appreciate any help offered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is,remove your Math.round() function,you see it is rounding of the values of the sin() function.This I know will generate error in the drawLine functionas it takes only integer arguments,to solve that type cast that to prevent lossy conversion.Like this:

g.drawLine((int) xStart,(int) yStart, (int) xEnd, (int) yEnd);